# Usar $index sin un ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estoy intentando, subir unos videos a un sitio y me sucede que si cargo uno funciona perfecto, pero si son mas, no se puede reproducir ninguno. Sospecho que lo que pasa es que tengo un mismo ng-click para reproducir todos los videos, entonces se deben estar pisando...
Hay alguna manera de usar una especi de $index sin el ng-repeat o generar ese numero dinamicamente para pasarlo de parametro?
este es mi codigo
Gracias!

```
html
    <div id="video-section" class="wide-rail-item player-section-video" ng-if="ready">
        <div>
            <player content="content"></player>
        </div>
    </div>


directive.js

            $scope.click = function(){

                var showPlayer = function() {
                    angular.element("#image-section").remove();
                    $scope.ready = true;
                };
    }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el contenido suficiente para saber donde llamas la funcion **Click** y donde tienes el **ng-repeat**

Answer (score 0):

Si estas obteniendo una lista de videos desde un servicio API lo ideal es usar un ng-repeat para mostrarlos en tu sitio web. Puedes usar un ng-click con una función que reciba como parámetro la película como tal y luego en tu controlador hace uso de la url de la película. Mira este ejemplo:

```html
<!doctype html >
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">

    <div >
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="movie in main.movies">
               <a href="" ng-click="main.goToMovie(movie);">{{movie.name}}</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Movie: {{main.movieSelected.name}}</h1>
        <p>Url: {{main.movieSelected.link}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .controller('MainController', function () {
                var main = this;
                main.movieSelected = null;
                main.movies = [
                    { name: 'movie 1', link: 'http://hosting/movie1'},
                    { name: 'movie 2', link: 'http://hosting/movie2'},
                    { name: 'movie 3', link: 'http://hosting/movie3'},
                    { name: 'movie 4', link: 'http://hosting/movie4'}
                ];

                main.goToMovie = function (movie) {
                    main.movieSelected = movie;
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```